# If i wanted to change the color of a specific word entered in textview, How would i do that?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, swift2

From what i've read i would need to use rangeOfString to search a textview entry but am unsure about how to go about that. Is it possible to change the color of a text entered in textview in real time, for example if someone wrote "blue," could i change the word to blue the moment they typed it. If so how would i go about that? I'm very new to coding and even newer to swift.

Comment: Being new, doesn't give you a pass on putting effort in yourself. Please try first, start by reading documentation. I'll lead you in the right direction, but you can't expect people to do everything for you. That's not what SO is about. You should review `UITextView` references and documentation and to answer how to change something in a `UITextView` you should look at `NSAttributedString` or `NSMutableAttributedString`

Comment: Before making such comments maybe you should make yourself aware of the series of syntax changes made between swift 1 and swift 2, such as countElements being changed simply to count. I'm not asking for anyone to write anything for me, just point me in the right direction. Even using solutions from the official documentation such as let boldRange = text.rangeOfString(NSLocalizedString("bold", comment: "")) don't always run correctly. I'm asking for people with experience with this language to help me toward a solution. If you won't offer assistance perhaps your better off not commenting.

Comment: It's not a personal attack. Its a way to encourage newcomers to get involved with research and trying things on their own. Not only does this limit duplicate questions (which are common on this site), it potentially limits vague answers, like the one below. Following [SO Guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a good question, some of the key notes in there are research, __showing effort__, providing code to narrow a solution down tremendously, also omits users from submitting an answer that has nothing to do with the topic. Keeps a clean and clutter free site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use attributed text for your text view and then use the `textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool` method, which will be triggered whenever the text in the text view's text changes. Apply your own logic in there as to what range the colored text will fall into and how that will happen...

Make sure your controller conforms to the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol and make the textView's delegate your controller.

Demonstration:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.textView.delegate = self // important! Otherwise the textView will not know where to call the delegate functions!
    }

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

        // first make sure that the text field is the one we want to actually change
        if textView == self.textView{

            let nsString = textView.text as NSString // we explicitly cast the Swift string to NSString so that we can use rangeOfString for example 
            let stringLength = textView.text.characters.count
            // Arbitrarily check if the string in the text field is not empty
            // Apply your own logic for when to update the string
            if stringLength > 0{

                let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
                // Currently the range is assumed to be the whole text (the range covers the whole string)
                // You'll have to apply your own logic here
                text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, stringLength))

                textView.attributedText = text

            }
        }
        return true

    }

}
```

For example, instead of using the above to color the whole text

<strike>text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, stringLength))</strike>

Color the first occurence of "hello" in red:

```
text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: nsString.rangeOfString("hello"))
```

Note that I explicitly cast the `textView`'s text to `NSString` so that we can use the range functions such as (`rangeOfString()`)

Comment: okay so I found out the issue i'm having with this answer and a few others like it is that in swift count is no longer a member of string. Is there any way to get around this.

Comment: I think the issue is, that you need to learn to do more research by yourself. In the new Swift, Swift strings have a different structure, you can access the length of a string by something like this: `str.characters.count`.

Answer (score 0):

Changes were made to swift in which count no longer seems to work with String. I made a slight change to the answer given by the_critic (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066899/the-critic). Thank you to all who helped

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.textView.delegate = self // important! Otherwise the textView will not know where to call the delegate functions!
}

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

    // first make sure that the text field is the one we want to actually change
    if textView == self.textView{

        let nsString = textView.text as NSString // we explicitly cast the Swift string to NSString so that we can use rangeOfString for example 
         let stringLength = textView.text.characters.count
        // Arbitrarily check if the string in the text field is not
```

empty
            // Apply your own logic for when to update the string
            if stringLength > 0{

```
            let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
            // Currently the range is assumed to be the whole text (the range covers the whole string)
            // You'll have to apply your own logic here
            text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, stringLength))

            textView.attributedText = text

        }
    }
    return true

}
```

}